# Using WFS-T when layer dimensions don't match with geometry dimensions

Tags: wfs, boundless-suite, oracle-spatial, wfs-t

We are able to Delete features from OpenLayers and it is successfully deleting them from spatial table. However we are unsuccessful doing add/edit from OpenLayers and saving the features in the Spatial table. We get the below exception while saving the data to spatial table.

```
ORA-13364: Layer Dimensionality does not match geometry dimensions
```

We believe the reason for the above is

1. geom data is 3D (shown below)
   `MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(3769.32886113393,2912.01336714121,0,3769.32885753005,2507.00004178244,0)`
2. we defined a custom SRID with 2D and using.
3. when we are querying (GetFeature) the data is returned in 2D format.

During edit functionality the data is going as 2D format and Oracle is throwing exception. Is there any way to avoid this issue that while saving to spatial table, such that the 2D data can be converted to 3D and saved?

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers is only the javascript API. What server do you use underneath to access the Oracle database ? Is that GeoServer ?

Something on the path to the database clearly thinks it should write geometries in 3D, setting all Z to 0. That will of course fail as you observe since the database table is 2D. It could be the OpenLayers editing. Could be the app server (Geoserver ?) ? A bit of debugging and tracing the interactions between OpenLayers and the server should point to the culprit.

If you do not want to do any of this, then there is a way around the issue: add an update/insert trigger onto your spatial column(s) to turn 3D shapes into 2D. But use that only if you are unable to find a way to fix your application, OpenLayers or GeoServer (if this is what you use).